# thread synchronised confused by lock(this)

Tags: c#

I hava a class:

```
 public class LockTest
 {
    public void LockThis()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("lock this test");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }

 }
```

in Main:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
LockTest lockTest = new LockTest();

lock (lockTest)
{
        //lockTest.LockThis();
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new Thread(lockTest.LockThis);
        thread.Start();
}
Console.Read();
}
```

I thought the invoking lockTest.LockThis() will cause a dead lock but it didn't. I don't konw why.

Comment: Add a `Thread.Wait()` and it should lock when i'm correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation here is timing.

The code in `Main` that starts the thread manages to escape the lock *before* the thread has fully started and gotten to the point where it too will try to take the lock.

Try moving the `Console.Read` line into the `lock` block, and you'll see what I mean.

Also note that even if the thread managed to reach the locking code before the `Main` method has escaped the lock, it will simply wait for that to happen (wait for the main thread to escape the lock), and then continue onwards.

So there is no deadlock here, *at all*.

A deadlock is when two threads wait for each other, or something similar. You don't have that in this code.

Comment: It's important to note that even if he moves the `Console.Read` he won't have a deadlock. He will only have a waiting thread that can be made run by simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I did some changes:add Console.WriteLine("Main running {0}",DateTime.Now);Thread.Sleep(10000); under thread.Start(); and change Console.WriteLine("lock this test"); to Console.WriteLine("LockThis running {0}",DateTime.Now); finally see what you said. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no deadlock in this code.

When the thread `LockThis` starts, the lock is owned by the main thread, so it starts and then it goes on wait. The main thread continues and exits the lock (the line before the `Console.Read`). At this time the `LockThis` thread can continue. No deadlock.

```
Main Thread     LockThis
lock            (not started)
start LockThis
                try lock, failure, goes in wait
unlock
Console.Read()
                awakened because the lock is free
                lock
                unlock
```

Another scenario: the main thread starts the `LockThis` thread. The main thread then continues and exits the lock before the LockThis thread has even begun working, so before it tries to enter the lock. Even in this scenario there is no deadlock.

```
Main Thread      LockThis
lock             (not started)
start LockThis
unlock
                 lock
Console.Read()
                 unlock
```

(note that in both cases, the position of the unlock in LockThis is irrelevant. You can move it up or down)

If you look at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) you'll see that to have a deadlock one has to have

> At least two resources must be non-shareable.

You here have only one resource (the `lock (lockTest)`).

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving the lock(lockTest) block before the thread locks lockTest.